# dynamic array only show me the last value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a map with the following code

```
var overlays = {
                 'Rain': L.tileLayer.provider('OpenWeatherMap.PrecipitationClassic'),
                 'Wind': L.tileLayer.provider('OpenWeatherMap.Wind')
               };

L.control.layers(baseLayers,overlays).addTo(map);
```

it works perfect, but now I need to do the same but dinamically. I am doing it this way but only shows me the last value:

```
    var key1= "Rain";
    var value1= "L.tileLayer.provider('OpenWeatherMap.PrecipitationClassic')";
    var key2= "Wind";
    var value2= "L.tileLayer.provider('OpenWeatherMap.Temperature')";   

    overlays[key1] = value1;
    overlays[key2] = value2;

    L.control.layers(baseLayers,overlays).addTo(map);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: code and question updated